# jquery datepicker is firing a button event under the calendar when a day is selected

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

When the date text box gains focus, the calendar pops up. The day that I need to choose is directly over a button underneath the calendar. When the day is clicked the button event behind the calendar is fired. I could move the button further down on the form but this is an issue for phones and is not a good solution. I am relatively new to the jquery development environment and would appreciate any solution.

Here is the button control:

Search

Thanks,

John

Comment: I've also discovered that you cannot select a date on the calendar in the area that is positioned over a button that has been disabled.

Answer (score 0):

After days of searching I finally found a solution. The z-index must be added to the datepicker css.

```
.ui-datepicker { width: 17em; padding: .2em .2em 0; display: none; z-index:9999 !important; }
                                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This solved my problem and just wanted to share.